# IP Header version 5?

Tags: c, network-programming, ip

I have following code in packet sniffer:

```
struct ip_header {
       unsigned char ip_ver:4;
...
};

...

printf("Version: %i\n", (int)ip_hdr->ip_ver)
```

The output of ths is "Version: 5". I think version can onl be 4 or 6, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it it is just the Header length first 4 bits and version is second 4bits, so it should be

```
struct ip_header {
       unsigned char ip_hl:4;
       unsigned char ip_ver:4;
...
};
```